# SVG textLength adds spacing before text

Tags: css, svg, text, padding

I have an SVG element with curved text around a circle, the text length is set to justify the text inside a white band, as follows:

```html
<svg width="720" height="504" viewBox="-2100 -1470 4200 2940">
  <style>
svg { background-color: #2196f3 }
text { font: bold 6rem/1 Arial, sans-serif }
  </style>
  <defs>
<path
  id="arc"
  d="M -300,620 a 1680 1680 0 0 1 3360,0"
  transform="rotate(81.81)"
/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="band">
<circle r="735"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path d="M -2205,1470 a 1785 1785 0 0 1 3570,0 h -105 a 1680 1680 0 0 0 -3360,0 z" clip-path="url(#band)" fill="#fff"/>
  <text fill="#009b3a" textLength="1432">
<textPath href="#arc">
  The text written in the band
</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

And it works just fine with longer text.

[image: text working fine]

However, the text is defined by the user, and can be very short. In this case, padding is being added before the text, but not after.

[image: text working bad]

How do I fix this unwanted left padding? I'm fine with either the same spacing both sides of the text, or no spaces on both sides, as long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This is to demonstrate that you are wrong. There is no space being added before the text. However your example is not working properly and textLength is not applied. I'm using textLength for the textPath element.

```html
<svg viewBox="-800 -800 1600 1600">
  <clipPath id="band">
    <circle r="735" />
  </clipPath>
  <path d="M -2205,1470 a 1785 1785 0 0 1 3570,0 h -105 a 1680 1680 0 0 0 -3360,0 z" clip-path="url(#band)" fill="#f00" />
  <path id="arc" d="M -300,620 a 1680 1680 0 0 1 3360,0" transform="rotate(81.81)" />
  <text font-size="100">
    <textPath href="#arc" textLength="1432" lengthAdjust="spacing">
           short
    </textPath>
  </text>

  <circle r="735" stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my snippet, there were some things missing. In your snippet, textLength is not applied, and the text takes the usual amount of space, not expanding to fill the band.